# Exporting superscript notation in pandas dataframe to csv or excel

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to write the foll. to a csv file:

```
  df.loc[0] = ['Total (2000)',
                       numpy.nan,
                       numpy.nan,
                       numpy.nan,
                       2.0,
                       1.6,
                       '10^6 km^2']
```

Is there a way to do that while writing '10^6 km^2' in a format such that the 6 is a superscript to 10 and 2 is a superscript to km. If not possible in csv, can I export to excel?

Comment: Please clarify what you want to write to the file. Assignment statements do not return a value so there is nothing to write here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible way is to change the actual contents of the dataframe before writing it to a csv (but you can automate this somewhat).

As a proof of concept, using `'\u2076'` as the unicode representation of superscript 6:

```
In [21]: df
Out[21]: 
              a   b   c   d  e    f          g
0  Total (2000) NaN NaN NaN  2  1.6  10^6 km^2

In [30]: df['g'] = (df['g'].str.replace("10\^6", u"10\u2076")
    ...:                   .str.replace("km\^2", u"km\u00b2"))

In [31]: df
Out[31]: 
              a   b   c   d  e    f        g
0  Total (2000) NaN NaN NaN  2  1.6  10⁶ km²

In [32]: print df.to_csv(encoding='UTF-8', index=False)
a,b,c,d,e,f,g
Total (2000),,,,2.0,1.6,10⁶ km²
```

Comment: Are you sure you made it unicode? (using the `u` before the strings) And does it look correct when you print it? (for me the csv file shows the km² correctly, the superscript 6 apparantly not, but that's maybe due to my editor)

Comment: thanks @joris, I did miss the `u`. After adding it, I see garbled text: `10â¶ kmÂ²`

Comment: this is what I am using: u'10\u2076 km\u00b2'

Comment: That means that the editor with which you are viewing the file does not support these unicode characters.

Comment: Ah ok, I tried using microsoft excel and notepad++. What editor are you using?

Comment: Notepad++ is showing the km² correctly for me, but not the superscript 6. Using the atom editor, everything is displayed fine.