# How to use subscript in data frames for table output in .csv format?

Tags: r, csv, datatables, format, export

Is it possible to export .csv tables where cell entries have subscripts?
i.e. for t-values where degrees of freedom are given in subscripts, etc.

I tried

```
set.seed(1234)
test <- data.frame(F1 = gl(5,5, labels=c("A","B","C","D","E")),
                   V1 = rnorm(25,5,2.1))

test$V2 <- expression(paste(test$F1[test$V1]))
View(test)
```

But its not working,...

The output should look sth. like this: x² 
but with a sub- not a superscript

The goal is to get a table like this(lhs) or in another way also like rhs:

[image]

Or does anybody know a good way to process the data in excel afterwards?

Comment: Could you provide the output that you want to see in your question. I am having a trouble interpreting what you mean by subscript.

Comment: You managed to get markdown to display a superscript but a CSV file destination suggest that the superscripted "2" would not be a specific character. What is the endgame here? Destination applications or evaluation framework?

Comment: This post may be what you are after: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35254956/3810603