# Create a superscript in .txt or .csv output

Tags: r, csv, txt

I am managing a list of many co-authors with affiliations from a database and am trying to get a nice list output that has the following format:

First Last 1

1 Affiliation, Institution, City, Country, ORCID

The "1" however needs to be a superscript in the output (either csv, or txt, .doc, whatever) and I can't figure out how to get it.

Comment: There might be a way to use Quarto/Markdown to accomplish this. For a simple text format (e.g. .csv/.txt) you may need to use unicode (see here for an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35226463/exporting-superscript-notation-in-pandas-dataframe-to-csv-or-excel/35254956).

Comment: See https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00B9